# Changing the range of sizes used in a bubble plot

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I'm using R to create a competitive map of strategic groups in the industry I'm researching. The number of outlets is along the x-axis, Sales is the y-axis as well as the size of the bubble.  Code used:

```
qplot(data = supermarket, x = outlets, y = sales, size = sales, color = retailer)
```

However, I need to increase the overall size of the bubbles as it is too unclear at the moment. Please see below for an example.

[image: Graph]

What I need is to have the bubbles keep their size relative to sales but become larger overall to increase the visibility.

Comment: @bdemarest, just noticed you beat me to the answer here.  Just had the same question myself a few days back.

Comment: Link above is defunct.

Answer (score 11):

Play with: `+ scale_size_continuous(range = c())` as in:

```
#set.seed(10)
#supermarket <- data.frame(sales = sample(1:50000, 12), 
#    outlets = sample(1:3000, 12), retailer = LETTERS[1:12])

#I use ggplot rather than qplot and understand it so that's what I used here
ggplot(data = supermarket, aes(x=outlets, y=sales, size=sales, color=retailer)) + 
            geom_point() + scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 8))
```

Or you can just use your  code and add the `scale_size_continuous` as bdemarest suggests above:

```
qplot(data = supermarket, x = outlets, y = sales, size = sales, color = retailer) + 
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 8))
```

Both will yield the same results.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much, this almost perfect. However, if i want to change LETTERS into the column names (the names of the supermarkets) which command should i use?

Comment: Use your data.  They're only letters because I made up data.

Comment: Thanks. But which 'code' (object?) should i use instead of LETTERS ?

Comment: By looking at your code you have 3 columns: `sales`, `outlets`, & `retailer`.  Use those.  In fact you can ignore the first part of my code as you already have this in a dataframe (I'll gray it out) I just provided the sample dataframe (as you should do when you ask a question) to make the outcome reproducible for future searchers with a similar question.