# Does point area not increase linearly with size with scale_size_continuous?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2 3.1.0, I'm confused about how `scale_size_continuous` works. The help documentation seems to suggest that the size scale is controlling point area, with `trans="identity"`. Yet it's clear this isn't what's happening.

```
library(tidyverse)

#make data
plotdat<-data.frame(x=runif(6), y=runif(6), size=seq(10,60,10))

#simple plot
plotdat %>% ggplot(aes(x, y, size=size))+
geom_point()+
scale_size_continuous()
```

[image: not scaling the way I expect]

```
#but help file seems to indicate that scale_size scales point area 
?scale_size_continuous
```

There is a note in the documentation that `scale_size_area` ensures that when size==0, the point will have 0 area. If I use this, then it appears that the point area increases linearly with `size`.

```
#simple plot
plotdat %>% ggplot(aes(x, y, size=size))+
geom_point()+
scale_size_area()
```

[image: is scaling the way I'd expect]

What is actually happening with `scale_size_continuous`-- how does it translate the `size` argument to point area?

**EDIT** after several comments I have a suspicion: perhaps both `scale_size_continuous` and `scale_size_area` increase linearly with size, but have different intercepts. Thus the fact that the point associated with size 20 in the first plot is way more than double the area of the point with size 10 is ok, because approximately the same number of pixels are added between 10 and 20 as between 20 and 30 or 40 and 50.

This is not the behavior I would expect when using, e.g. point size to indicate the number of individuals, but is consistent with area increasing linearly with size, within `range`.

Comment: The sizes are changing. How do you know it isn't scaling linearly? Are you measuring the area with some other tool?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570821/changing-the-range-of-sizes-used-in-a-bubble-plot I think it's linear, as you can see from the source code. Couldn't find documentation. **EDIT** Maybe not as a comment on this post recommends changing the range until it looks right!

Comment: Hmm. I just measured again with a ruler. On my screen, the diameter point associated with size 10 is about 1mm, 20 about 3 mm, 30 about 4mm, 60 looks just shy of 5 mm.

Comment: @Michael, would it work for your needs to use `geom_circle` instead of `geom_point`, and map `r` to the square root of the desired area?

Comment: It works fine for my purpose to simply use `geom_point` and `scale_size_area`. But I'd love to know why `scale_size_continuous` doesn't also work this way and what it's doing instead. Great suggestion though!

Comment: If you want size to scale linearly with the diameter / radius, use `scale_radius` instead.