# Can't get geom_sf line width to function properly when I provide its value through an aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a shapefile, `my_sf`. If I write:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data = my_sf,
    size = 0.5 # this is the default value actually
  )
```

then it works just fine. However, if I add a `my_line_width` attribute to `my_sf`, and set each value in that column to 0.5, and then write:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data = my_sf,
    aes(size = my_line_width)
  )
```

then I get a bunch of massive lines that overlap hideously. If the normal lines are width 0.5, then these are perhaps width 4. **I don't understand why those don't produce the same result** (aside from the legend, which I know only pops up if you use an aesthetic). Does anyone know what's going on?

I have also tried using `lwd` instead of `size`. Exactly the same thing happens: it's fine when I just set a static value, but when I try to provide values through an aesthetic, it goes wrong.

Comment: you generally need `_scale_*_identity` when passing values like this to `aes` , maybe try `scale_size_identity()`

Comment: Note new conventions for setting linewidth as of ggplot2 3.4 https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/ggplot2-3-4-0/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the idea behind `aes` mapping the data to the plot. For example, see [Difference between passing options in aes() and outside of it in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511911/difference-between-passing-options-in-aes-and-outside-of-it-in-ggplot2) or [When does the aesthetic go inside or outside aes()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863049/when-does-the-aesthetic-go-inside-or-outside-aes). Use `size` or whatever inside `aes` to map data to the aesthetic in whatever way `ggplot` will understand it (more on that below) or outside `aes` with a constant value to actually get `ggplot` to use that value.  The behavior you are finding is true with ggplot generally and not specific to `geom_sf`.

You can see that this is true for size even with `geom_point`

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(mpg, wt, size=cyl))+geom_point()
k<-4
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(mpg, wt, size=k))+geom_point()
k<-6
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(mpg, wt, size=k))+geom_point()
k<-10
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(mpg, wt, size=k))+geom_point()
```

Also, the default treatment of size is pretty confusing with ggplot2, IMO: [Does point area not increase linearly with size with scale_size_continuous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54220012/8400969). When only provided 1 value inside aes, the line thickness will probably always be the baseline default size. As your commenter noted, you can adjust this behavior with `scale`, and you can use "identity" to some extent but it may be helpful to provide a `range` https://stackoverflow.com/a/11570926/8400969.

Comment: Appending `+ scale_size_identity()` solved the issue with a little bit of tweaking, thanks.

Comment: ggplot2 3.4.0 replaces `size` with `linewidth`, so make sure you use that all who see this in the future. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/ggplot2-3-4-0/

Answer (score 6):

As I overlooked the comments ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548680/cant-get-geom-sf-line-width-to-function-properly-when-i-provide-its-value-throu#comment132106483_54613325) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548680/cant-get-geom-sf-line-width-to-function-properly-when-i-provide-its-value-throu#comment131580243_54548680)):

In ggplot version 3.4 `linewidth` was introduced!!

https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/ggplot2-3-4-0/#hello-linewidth